# MKCircle drawn with a radius defined by two far points renders incorrect

Tags: ios, mapkit

I have created a Map display that plots 2 points and would like to create a MKCircle that is centered on 1 of the points and has the edge of the circle pass through the other point. This should be as easy as creating a circle with a radius equal to distance between the 2 points and centering the circle around one of the points. This seems to work just fine across smaller distances, but after a certain distance the radius of the circle no longer matches up with the 2nd point. (In my testing I plotted a points on LA and NY).

I am getting my radius in meters using:

```
CLLocationDistance dist = [loc1 distanceFromLocation:loc2];
NSLog(@"dist: %f", dist);
```

And I am drawing the circles using:

```
MKCircle *circle = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:coord1 radius:dist];
[circle setTitle:@"background"];
[mMapView addOverlay: circle];
MKCircle *circleLine = [MKCircle circleWithCenterCoordinate:coord2 radius:dist];
[circleLine setTitle:@"line"];
[mMapView addOverlay: circleLine];
```

Is there something I am missing here? It is quite frustrating to have the circle close but off by just a bit. At smaller distances I can zoom in the max amount and have the pin exactly touch the outer line of my circle.

Answer (score 0):

The trouble is probably because NY and LA are at different latitudes and a circle of radius X meters centered at the equator is smaller on the map than another circle with the same radius nearer the poles. Look at the second map on this page if you need a picture http://www.gpsvisualizer.com/examples/range_rings.html

So how to get the right radius? If you know what zoom level you're going to be displaying it at you could try this (completely untested) algorithm:

```
1. Convert the two geo-points to map points
2. Workout the distance in map points
3. use that distance to create a new map point at the same y coordinate offset from the center point (full left or full right won't matter)
4. convert this point to a geo-point
5. workout the distance between it at the center geo-point
6. use that as your radius.
```